# Want to delete Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have around 600+ Jenkins jobs which needs to be removed since those are no longer being used.
Could any one suggest what are the ways we can remove those jobs easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Jenkins Console (`https://<url>/script`) and execute a groovy script like this one

```
import jenkins.model.*

def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
    job.name =~ /my_regex_here/
}

matchedJobs.each { job ->
    println job.name
    job.delete()
}
```

https://gist.github.com/nextrevision/d11b2df4e8b229c6855b

If the jobs are inside folders, look at the script shared by pjlbyrne

Comment: If you want to delete everything except one job, you can have something like that in regex `job.name =~ /^((?!some_job_name_to_preserve).)*$/`